# ChartJS onClick throws Error with react-router;

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

i am trying to redirect user to specific path with react router when they click on bar in the chart. But chartjs throws error;

```
"react-chartjs-2": "^4.2.0",
"chart.js": "^3.8.0",


Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'handleEvent')
    at Object.afterEvent (chart.esm.js:8068:1)
    at callback (helpers.segment.js:92:1)
    at PluginService._notify (chart.esm.js:4946:1)
    at PluginService.notify (chart.esm.js:4933:1)
    at Chart.notifyPlugins (chart.esm.js:6074:1)
    at Chart._eventHandler (chart.esm.js:6101:1)
    at listener (chart.esm.js:5979:1)
    at Chart.event (chart.esm.js:3224:1)
    at helpers.segment.js:28:1
```

I traced the error and it seems to be thrown here in the legend method of chartjs library:

```
 afterEvent(chart, args) {
    if (!args.replay) {
      chart.legend.handleEvent(args.event);
    }
  },
```

My code:

```
   const navigate = useNavigate();
    const options: ChartOptions<"bar"> = {
        onClick: (event, elements, chart) => {
            navigate("/path")
     
}
```

Comment: What is `chart.legend`? What declares, or defines, it? Is this something that needs to be configured in the chart.js code/logic? [mcve]

Comment: That is some code inside the library itself in node_modules which i cant modify. I tried with legends enable of chart also disabled but both cases throws error. 

The error tracking shows that it blows in chart.legend.handleEvent, in file that is in the node_modules.

Comment: Just experienced the same thing - did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I couldnt. I just did some wierd hacky way. Basically i set state from chartjs with onClick and then useEffect was checking for that state change and if state changed then router was navigating.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error eventhough i disabled legend plugin in chartjs options

```
plugins: {
  legend: {
    display: false
   }
 }
```

turns out, we need to filter legend events like this:

```
plugins: {
  legend: {
    display: false,
    events: []
  },
}
```